# How to add attributes to decorated functions when combining decorators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Two function decorators are defined.
The target is to detect if 0, 1, or 2 decorators are applied to a function.

Why does the below code return "False" for the 2nd decorator?

```
def decorator1(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        f(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapped.dec1 = True
    return wrapped


def decorator2(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        f(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapped.dec2 = True
    return wrapped


@decorator1
@decorator2
def myfunc():
    print(f"running myfunc")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfunc()

    print(f"myfunc has decorator1: {getattr(myfunc, 'dec1', False)}")
    print(f"myfunc has decorator2: {getattr(myfunc, 'dec2', False)}")
```

Result:

```
running myfunc
myfunc has decorator1: True 
myfunc has decorator2: False
```

I am using Python 3.9.

Comment: Because `wrapped` in decorator1 is not equal to `wrapped` in decorator2

Comment: What do you mean? Can you suggest a correction pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this sentence in print statement is not correct: "myfunc has...". No. `myfunc` has neither `dec1` nor `dec2`. What you get back from calling your decorator is a new function not the function you passed. I'll explain it.

This code:

```py
@decorator1
@decorator2
def myfunc():
    print(f"running myfunc")
```

is equivalent to:

```py
def myfunc():
    print('running myfunc')

myfunc = decorator2(myfunc)
myfunc = decorator1(myfunc)
```

Remember that you add those dynamic attributes to the `wrapped` functions. They don't both apply to the same `myfunc` function object. They apply to "*their*" wrapped function. The wrapped functions are two different objects in those two decorators:

```py
myfunc = decorator2(myfunc)
print(myfunc)   # <function decorator2.<locals>.wrapped at 0x1028456c0>
myfunc = decorator1(myfunc)
print(myfunc)   # <function decorator1.<locals>.wrapped at 0x102845760>
```

After stacking decorators, you can expect the `decorator1.<locals>.wrapped` to have `dec1`(because it's the outer one) but it doesn't have `dec2`. It's on the `decorator2.<locals>.wrapped`:

```py
def decorator1(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.dec1 = True
    return wrapped


def decorator2(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.dec2 = True
    return wrapped


def myfunc():
    print('running myfunc')


myfunc = decorator2(myfunc)
myfunc = decorator1(myfunc)


print(f"{getattr(myfunc, 'dec1', False)}")  # True
print(f"{getattr(myfunc.__closure__[0].cell_contents, 'dec2', False)}")  # True
```

If you had these kinds of decorators, your assumptions would work:

```py
def decorator1(f):
    f.dec1 = True
    return f

def decorator2(f):
    f.dec2 = True
    return f

@decorator1
@decorator2
def myfunc():
    print('running myfunc')

print(f"{getattr(myfunc, 'dec1', False)}")  # True
print(f"{getattr(myfunc, 'dec2', False)}")  # True
```

---

##### How can you achieve it with your existing code?

I don't think it's a clean way but it works if you want:

```py
def decorator1(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    while hasattr(f, '__wrapped__'):
        f = f.__wrapped__
    f.dec1 = True
    wrapped.__wrapped__ = f
    return wrapped

def decorator2(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    while hasattr(f, '__wrapped__'):
        f = f.__wrapped__
    f.dec2 = True
    wrapped.__wrapped__ = f
    return wrapped

@decorator1
@decorator2
def myfunc():
    print('running myfunc')

print(f"{getattr(myfunc.__wrapped__, 'dec1', False)}")  # True
print(f"{getattr(myfunc.__wrapped__, 'dec2', False)}")  # True
```

You see, with that while loop, I go deep inside to find the original `myfunc` and add it to the returned wrapped function. Also I add the `decX` attributes to the original `myfunc`.

Comment: Interesting, but not really intuitive. Is there a "clean" way to get the expected behaviour, or is the conclusion that combining 2 function decorators with dynamic attributes is a "no go"?

Comment: @Davy what's your usecase exactly? What S. B. showed first seemed quite intuitive and "clean" to me.

Comment: Indeed, with the update (new decorators), this is a clean solution.  Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a separate attribute from each decorator, you could have the decorators cooperate and add their tag to a shared attribute, a list.

```
def decorator1(f):
    decorators = getattr(f, "dec", [])
    decorators.append("dec1")

    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        f(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapped.dec = decorators
    return wrapped

def decorator2(f):
    decorators = getattr(f, "dec", [])
    decorators.append("dec2")

    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        f(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapped.dec = decorators
    return wrapped

def f0():
    print("running f0")

@decorator1
def f1():
    print("running f1")

@decorator2
def f2():
    print("running f2")

@decorator1
@decorator2
def f3():
    print("running f3")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f0()
    f1()
    f2()
    f3()
    print(f"f0 has decorators: {getattr(f0, 'dec', [])}")  # []
    print(f"f1 has decorators: {getattr(f1, 'dec', [])}")  # ['dec1']
    print(f"f2 has decorators: {getattr(f2, 'dec', [])}")  # ['dec2']
    print(f"f3 has decorators: {getattr(f3, 'dec', [])}")  # ['dec2', 'dec1']
```